# Python File Object

Tags: python, file-io

I am passing a file object as an argument to a function in Python. Inside this function I want to read the content of the file passed as an argument.

Will I be able to read the file from the beginning or will it continue from the last line read before passing it to the current function ?

Comment: from the next line...

Comment: It is easy to test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't coded in python much, but I would assume that the parameter you passed in is actually a reference to the object, which means that it should read from the next line. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) for clarification.

Answer (score 6):

This is something you could easily find out yourself by testing. The filehandle remembers it's current line so it will continue reading where it left of.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer twice or more - why do people waiste everyone's time asking questions they could answer by themselves in less time than they spent posting the question, I really wonder...

Answer (score 0):

File objects are generators, so they will continue from the next line.

Comment: "Hence why you can't use them once read or readlines has been called" : you may want to read about `file.seek(0)`.

Comment: "they will continue from the next line. " : unless you call `.seek(0)` which will reset the pointer at the beginning of the file

Comment: "it will continue where it left off" _unless_ you reset the file pointer using `file.seek()`

Answer (score 0):

You might find https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects helpful. The file object keeps track of where it is.